# O que significa o cifrão "$" no console do navegador ou no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, navegador-de-internet, console

Numa página qualquer vazia (sem biblioteca alguma), ao digitar um `$` no console do navegador é retornado uma função, como mostra a saída abaixo:

```
ƒ $(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }
```

Se eu digitar dois `$` o resultado é parecido:

```
ƒ $$(selector, [startNode]) { [Command Line API] }
```

Se digitar três `$`, recebo erro:

> ```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: $$$ is not defined
> ```

Testei nos outros navegadores (IE11, Edge, Firefox) e todos retornam uma função, em alguns casos com saída ligeiramente diferente.

Mas se eu fizer `console.log($)` em um `<script>` da página, irá mostrar o erro `$ is not defined`:

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
   <script>
   console.log($);
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Gostaria de saber exatamente o que significa esse `$` (simples ou duplo) ou a função que ele retorna no console e qual seria a sua aplicação na prática?

Comment: Basicamente é uma utilidade para depurações do Chrome, se você não se importar com uma fonte externa, pode ler [isso](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities#queryselector)

Comment: @user140828 Que legal! Não conhecia essas funcionalidades do console. Obg! Passei a vista na página que mandou e já saquei logo o que isso significa. Já dá até pra postar uma resposta :D

Comment: Nota: no FF é a mesma coisa, não é exclusividade do Chrome

Comment: Variáveis `$0`,  `$1`, `$2`, etc também podem ser criadas pela aba ele "Elements" para armazenar elementos HTML desejados. Apenas uma curiosidade

Answer (score 10, accepted):

São atalhos presentes nas ferramentas do desenvolvedor.

- O cifrão `$` funciona como um atalho para [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).
- Já o `$$` funciona como um *alias* para [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). A única diferença é que, ao invés de retornar uma `NodeList`, retorna-se um `Array`. Provavelmente para a conveniência de se poder utilizar métodos do construtor `Array` diretamente.

É importante frisar que esses atalhos **não devem ser usados** em códigos "de produção", já que funcionam somente nas ferramentas de desenvolvedor.

Vale mencionar, ainda, que esse cifrão em questão `$` não é do jQuery. Ele só irá se referir à `jQuery` caso essa biblioteca for incluída na página. Nesse último caso, o atalho padrão à `document.querySelector` não estará mais disponível.

Existem diversas outras "utilidades" no console das ferramentas do desenvolvedor. [Este artigo](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities) fornece mais informações.

Comment: É isso mesmo. Mt bom!